# Importing Attachments with No Extension

Tags: attachments, import

Is there an extension, or a technique, during Wordpress import to pull in an attachment URL that doesn't have a file extension?

I'm trying to import a Square Space blog into Wordpress. Most of the posts and URLs come over, but there's a small number (eight), where the images can't be imported.  The importer fails with a message like

> Failed to import Media “attachment-50b1b915e4b01c11f0ef7db4”: Invalid file type

If I lookup the `attachment-50b1b915e4b01c11f0ef7db4` attachment in the XML import file, I find the following item node set

```
<item>
  <wp:attachment_url>http://static.squarespace.com/static/50a97ccee4b040d1420f6022/50a97ccee4b040d1420f6032/50b1b915e4b01c11f0ef7db4/1353824560608/file</wp:attachment_url>
  <link>http://static.squarespace.com/static/50a97ccee4b040d1420f6022/50a97ccee4b040d1420f6032/50b1b915e4b01c11f0ef7db4/1353824560608/file</link>
  <title>attachment-50b1b915e4b01c11f0ef7db4</title>
  <wp:post_name>file</wp:post_name>
  <wp:post_type>attachment</wp:post_type>
  <wp:post_id>91</wp:post_id>
  <wp:post_parent>90</wp:post_parent>
  <wp:status>inherit</wp:status>
  <content:encoded><![CDATA[img-50b1b915e4b01c11f0ef7db4]]></content:encoded>
  <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[exc-50b1b915e4b01c11f0ef7db4]]></excerpt:encoded>
  <pubDate>Sun, 25 Nov 2012 06:22:13 +0000</pubDate>
  <wp:post_date>2012-11-25 06:22:13</wp:post_date>
  <wp:post_date_gmt>2012-11-25 06:22:13</wp:post_date_gmt>
  <dc:creator>astorm@example.com</dc:creator>
</item>
```

Zooming in on the attachment URL, that's

```
http://static.squarespace.com/static/50a97ccee4b040d1420f6022/50a97ccee4b040d1420f6032/50b1b915e4b01c11f0ef7db4/1353824560608/file
```

There's no file extension on this URL. It appears that the `wordpress-importer` plugin checks the file types of the URL by extension, using the `wp_get_mime_types` function.

Is there a way to work around this by mapping via the `Content/Type` header, or manually mapping specific URLs to specific file types during import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no native solution popping up here, I ended up writing a script that

- Parsed my the XML import file I had and identified problem attachments
- Manually download those attachments with a file extension
- Upload those images to a new web server
- Alter the appropriate `link` and `wp:attachment_url` nodes to point to the new URLs
- Re-save the XML